# Multiple arrays creation using for loop

Tags: php, variables

How do you create 10 separate arrays using a for loop? For example my loop is from 1 to 10 and i want to create 10 arrays. I do this and it gives a notice and doesn't display my array.

```
for($i=0;$i<12;$i++)
{
$match.$i = array();
}
```

Comment: What is `$match`? What is this code for? Are you aware that your loop goes up to `11` and has 12 iterations? And are you aware that English sentences start with a capital letter, and questions end in a question mark like `?`?

Comment: `$match.$i` on the left-hand side of an expression is illegal syntax.

Comment: @MarcB: [No, it's not](http://codepad.org/AHphCVY0)

Comment: well, maybe not illegal, but definitely useless. if `$match` is "hello", then `$match.$i = array()` is going to produce `helloArray` and that gets assigned nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your loop code to this:

```
$match[$i] = array();
```

Comment: doesnt adding $match[$i] make my array a two dimensional array? i want to save it a 1 dimensional array.

Comment: please describe what EXACTLY you want to achieve, what should be the result ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
$myArray = array();
for ( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ )
{
  $myArray[$i] = array();
}
```

Comment: Yeeees, the `new` comes from JavaScript! ;)

Comment: still dont need it in js :-P `var param = [];`

Comment: doesnt adding $match[$i] or $myArray[$i] make my array a two dimensional array? i want to save it a 1 dimensional array. –

Comment: Yes, you're right. So do you want to create an array with 10 empty elements?

Comment: no i want to create 10 arrays using for loop. let me know if its even possible?